How to generate testing https URL for third party sandbox
I am currently integrating CLIO third party in my Localhost.
But i don't have production URL yet but clio is only allowing HTTPs.
I tried with 127.0.0.1 but still not working.
So need help with HTTPs support for localhost.

use ngrok it has free and paid version but free version is enough.
ngrok
